# Decoding and encoding strings for kotlinx.serialization.properties

Tags: kotlin, serialization, deserialization, properties-file, kotlinx.serialization

I'm currently struggling with the experimental KXS-properties serialization backend, mainly because of two reasons:

1. I can't find any documentation for it (I think there is none)
2. KXS-properties only includes a serializer / deserializer, but no encoder / decoder

The endpoint provided by the framework is essentially `Map<String, Any>`, but the map is flat and the keys already have the usual dot-separated properties syntax. So the step that I have to take is to encode the map to a single string that is printable to a `.properties` file AND decode a single string from a `.properties` file into the map. I'm generally following the Properties Format Spec from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader), it's not as easy as one might think.

The problem is that I can't use `java.util.Properties` right away because KXS is multiplatform and it would kinda kill the purpose of it when I'd restrict it to JVM because I use `java.util.Properties`. If I were to use it, the solution would be pretty simple, like this: https://gist.github.com/RaphaelTarita/748e02c06574b20c25ab96c87235096d

So I'm trying to implement my own encoder / decoder, following the rough structure of `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.kt`. Although it's pretty tedious, it went well so far, but now I've stumbled upon a new problem:

As far as I know (I am not sure because there is no documentation), the map only contains primitives (or primitive-equivalents, as Kotlin does not really have primitives). I suspect this because when you write your own `KSerializer`s for the KXS frontend, you can specify to encode to any primitive by invoking the `encodeXXX()` functions of the `Encoder` interface. Now the problem is: When I try to decode to the map that should contain primitives, how do I even know which primitives are expected by the model class?

I've once written my own serializer / deserializer in Java to learn about the topic, but in that implementation, the backend was a lot more tightly coupled to the frontend, so that I could query the expected primitive type from the model class in the backend. But in my situation, I don't have access to the model class and I have no clue how to retrieve the expected types.

As you can see, I've tried multiple approaches, but none of them worked right away. If you can help me to get *any* of these to work, that would be very much appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a documentation for kotlinx.serialization: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serialization-guide.md

Comment: Look at the [Structured map keys](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#allowing-structured-map-keys) section. I believe it will be a better choice for serializing maps than using Properties

Comment: Well, none of these things tell me anything I wouldn't know yet. The "documentation" about the properties serializer is not more that what I can find in the code comments of kotlinx-serialization-properties. And what do you mean by "Properties format is natively supported"? I couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Sorry, it's actually not, removed that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works in kotlinx.serialization is that there are serializers that describe classes and structures etc. as well as code that writes/read properties as well as the struct. It is then the job of the format to map those operations to/from a data format.

The intended purpose of kotlinx.serialization.Properties is to support serializing a Kotlin class to/from a java.util.Properties like structure. It is fairly simple in setup in that every nested property is serialized by prepending the property name to the name (the dotted properties syntax).

Unfortunately it is indeed the case that this deserializing from this format requires knowing the types expected. It doesn't just read from string. However, it is possible to determine the structure. You can use the `descriptor` property of the serializer to introspect the expectations.

From my perspective this format is a bit more simple than it should be. It is a good example of a custom format though. A key distinction between formats is whether they are intended to just provide a storage format, or whether the output is intended (be able to) to represent a well designed api. The latter ones need to be more complex.

Comment: Yep, I also figured out the descriptor part by now. I'm currently working on putting the whole thing together. I consider deploying this as a package somewhere, since it's a task that is definitely not trivial (as I had to find out). Thank you!